# Prevent lightdm from turning off screen when locking session

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, display-manager, lightdm-gtk-greeter, light-locker

I am running Xubuntu 18.04. When I lock the session, the screen gets turned off instantly. I am using stock lightdm as display manager and lightlocker for locking the session.

From my viewpoint the following sequence of events happens.

1. I initiate locking by running xflock4 via keyboard shortcut or clicking "Lock Screen" in the Whisker (Main) menu.
2. VT8 becomes active, a new lightdm greeter is spawned on this VT terminal and physical screen turns off at the same time.
3. My usual VT7 terminal gets seized in background with lightlocker which draws "This session is locked" screen.

If press some button on the keyboard or move the mouse, the screen turns on. If I press Control-Alt-F7, I see lightlocker lock screen in my original session. If I press Control-Alt-F8 I go back to the greeter where I can enter my password. After entering the password, VT7 becomes active and lightlocker white-on-black lock screen is no longer shown. If I later go back to VT8 with Control-Alt-F8, I see a completely black screen with only a blinking cursor (seems to be in text mode).

If the session timeouts and gets locked automatically, I also end up with the screen turned off. That can happen several times a day.

I am using an external monitor which is very slow to turn on again. It takes around 10 seconds and that is quite annoying every single time. I would rather keep it on for an hour or more on password dialog before timing it out and turning off automatically.

Also there is a non-zero chance of getting a system freeze due to buggy Intel (KMS?) drivers when doing VT switch and turning of the screen at *almost* the same time.

I skimmed through lightdm and lightdm greeter docs and found no hints on how to prevent that.

**Update 1**

1. I discovered an "Action" applet for the xfce4-panel that can "switch" user sessions without turning off the screen. This essentially locks the session with light-locker and shows greeter on a new VT. After some digging I discovered a command to show greeter, `dm-tool switch-to-greeter`. I have reassigned keyboard shortcut to lock the screen from `xflock4` to `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` as workaround. But the problem with automatic locking and turning screen still annoys me. What is interesting that `dm-tool lock` and `light-locker-command --lock` (xflock4 calls it) behave the same and produce a turned off monitor.
2. If I uninstall light-locker (with full reboot) and do `dm-tool lock`, the screen also turns off. So this should not be related to light-locker...

**Update 2**

The question is how to keep screen turned on when locking the session via light-locker on timeout or locking manually with xflock4, not on how to disable timeouts for locking.

Comment: Over on sister site askubuntu there are some [answers](https://askubuntu.com/q/942366/421483) to a similar question you might try. Basically, `xset -dpms s off` for `display-setup-script=` inside the `lightdm.conf`. It is for Ubuntu 16.04 but might provide clues.

Comment: Tried your half-solution with `dm-tool switch-to-greeter`. Unfortunately, it still allows you to switch back to the active session on VT7 without entering password.

Comment: You previously reassigned the hotkey from `xflock4` to a working lock command, but instead you should have configured xflock4 itself: `xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand -s "<a-working-lock-command>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) Xfce comes with a native screensaver. When I lock the session, the screensaver kicks in. If I lock the session in any way (lock icon click in Whisker, timeout, xflock4 command), the screensaver starts. If I move the mouse or press a mouse/keyboard button, the unlock dialog appears. The monitor stays on all this time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have a few options, depending on what you are looking for exactly:

### 1. Disable the display timeout/turning off when idle for too long, even to the point of infinity if so desired.

This operation is actually controlled by the screensaver, and can be disabled with `sudo xset s [timeout] [cycle]` , and to disable screen timeout and cycling (burn-in prevention) you can set it with the following:

```
sudo xset s 0 0
```

and in your case of 1 hour timeout you can set it to

```
sudo xset s 3600 3600
```

### 2. Display slow to turn back on/redisplay login

While theoretically possible for a monitor to take 10 seconds to turn back on (I personally haven't seen a screen do that since CRT TVs from the 80s and I doubt that was intended) I believe that what is actually happening is that while your display is still blank, your system behaves in the same way it does when you have the "screen is locked" white on black text visible.

This in most cases can be circumvented fairly easily, with switching to another terminal tty, let's say <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F4</kbd>. After logging in, you can execute

```
sudo loginctl unlock-session [ID]
```

or if you don't want to even bother finding the ID of your specific session:

```
sudo loginctl unlock-sessions
```

and then just hit <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F7</kbd> and you will already be all logged in and  have your x-window-manager ready to go.

Comment: 1. I do not want to disable automatic locking timeouts (I have updated the question to mention that) 2. The monitor is from 2011 and is really slow to turn on. I can use the session blindly while it is turning on and enter my password, but I would rather keep it turned on for a while after gtk greeter is shown to avoid system freezes.

Comment: then `sudo xset s 3600 3600 ` should still lock the session but not turn on the display screensaving features until after 1 hour passes.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work for me. I tried `xset s 10 600`. The screen still turns off as the result of Light Locker sending signal to LightDM. (And I get frequent freezes). I may want to look at the sources for `dm-tool` and lightdm, especially the codepath for `dm-tool lock` all the way to the final ioctl/syscall in LightDM itself resulting in turned off screen.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what is happening.  Try to run `light-locker-command -a` from the terminal (not as root). I am fairly certain your screen will just  go black for a second and then reactivate back to your desktop GUI right away. If so, run `xdg-screensaver status` (it will likely say enabled ),  followed by `xdg-screensaver activate`  (this will more than likely show the same behavior as `light-locker-command -a`) . Confirm these behaviors just so I know I am on the right track and  I will update my original post with the solution.

Comment: `xdg-screensaver status` shows `enabled` before and after the experiments, so light-locker process properly runs inside the session.
If I run `sleep 1; light-locker-command -a` the screen turns off. The same with `sleep 1; xdg-screensaver activate`. If I then move the mouse, I end up on the VT8 with LightDM GTK Greeter waiting for my password. The resulting behavior is identical to `dm-tool lock`, `xflock4` (it calls `light-locker-command --lock`): the screen turns off.

Comment: I assume that Light Locker acts as "screensaver" for X. When timeouts are reached X signals that to Light Locker and it in turn signals to LightDM "to lock". LightDM spawns Greeter on VT8 and turns off the screen at the same time. In case of timeouts, the screen turns off earlier by X server itself (`prefer blanking: yes` in `xset q`) and I do not see VT8 switch flickering as with `light-locker-command -a` and `xdg-screensaver activate`.

Comment: Actually, the behavior is actually exactly the same. There is flickering associated with VT switch in all scenarios. The external monitor is so slow to detect HDMI signal, that it does not turn on for a brief time to show VT8 switch. I can see laptop screen to turn on briefly to show black background with text cursor, then it disappears, then mouse cursor appears on black background and then screen finally turns off.